# Character conversion from SAS to TERADATA

Tags: sas, teradata

I have recently started a new job and I am using tools which I am not very familiar with. so i was wondering if the StackOverFlow family could help me out.

I have this concatenation in SAS, but I am not able to sort it out on TERADATA

```
t1.COD_CZ||PUT(INPUT(t1.CODTC,5.),z4.)||PUT(t1.PROGOPE,z8.) as CODIGO_MCT
```

I have written something like this, but then the length of the string is not harmonized with the the result in sas.

```
t1.COD_CZ|| cast(cast(t1.CODTC as int) as char(4))|| cast(t1.PROGOPE as char(8)) as CODIGO_MCT
```

Can you gently enlight me? thanks in advance

Comment: What's the data type of `t1.COD_CZ`and the exact result in SAS? Does `z8.` return `00012345`?

Comment: `cod_cz ` is a char 5 ;
`06540042800000058` is  an example of the expected outcome

Comment: @dnoeth :)) just replied you

Answer (score 0):

You must apply a FORMAT to get leading zeroes (concatenating trims trailing spaces):

```
t1.COD_CZ||Cast(t1.CODTC AS FORMAT '9(4)')||Cast(t1.PROGOPE AS FORMAT '9(8)')
```

The result has a fixed length, but it's still a VarChar(17). If you need fixed length, e.g. for export:

```
CAST(t1.COD_CZ||Cast(t1.CODTC AS FORMAT '9(4)')||Cast(t1.PROGOPE AS FORMAT '9(8)') AS CHAR(17))
```

Comment: Teradata returns me an error 3527
`format  string '9(4)' has combination of numeric, character and graphic values` ... 
I checked and CODTC is also a char

Comment: anyways, it works ... I just did not format the 2 variable

Comment: The CHAR(n) might return trailing spaces, if you want leading zeroes instead you can `LPAD(TRIM(CODTCO), 4, '0')`